# Spark converting dataframe to RDD takes a huge amount of time, lazy execution or real issue?

Tags: apache-spark

In my spark application, I am loading data from Solr into a dataframe, running an SQL query on it, and then writing the resulting dataframe to MongoDB.

I am using spark-solr library to read data from Solr and mongo-spark-connector to write results to MongoDB.

The problem is that it is very slow, for datasets as small as 90 rows in an RDD, the spark job takes around 6 minutes to complete (4 nodes, 96gb RAM, 32 cores each).

I am sure that reading from Solr and writing to MongoDB is not slow because outside Spark they perform very fast.

When I inspect running jobs/stages/tasks on application master UI, it always shows a specific line in this function as taking 99% of the time:

```scala
override def exportData(spark: SparkSession, result: DataFrame): Unit = {
    try {
      val mongoWriteConfig = configureWriteConfig
      MongoSpark.save(result.withColumn("resultOrder", monotonically_increasing_id())
        .rdd
        .map(row => {
          implicit val formats: DefaultFormats.type = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
          val rMap = Map(row.getValuesMap(row.schema.fieldNames.filterNot(_.equals("resultOrder"))).toSeq: _*)
          val m = Map[String, Any](
            "queryId" -> queryId,
            "queryIndex" -> opIndex,
            "resultOrder" -> row.getAs[Long]("resultOrder"),
            "result" -> rMap
          )

          Document.parse(Serialization.write(m))
        }), mongoWriteConfig);
    } catch {
      case e: SparkException => handleMongoException(e)
    }
}
```

The line `.rdd` is shown to take most of the time to execute. Other stages take a few seconds or less.

I know that converting a dataframe to an rdd is not an inexpensive call but for 90 rows it should not take this long. My local standalone spark instance can do it in a few seconds.

I understand that Spark executes transformations lazily. Does it mean that operations before `.rdd` call is taking a long time and it's just a display issue on application master UI? Or is it really the `dataframe` to `rdd` conversion taking too long? What can cause this?

By the way, SQL queries run on the dataframe are pretty simple ones, just a single `group by` etc.

Comment: Why do you need a RDD instead of a DataFrame to begin with ?
For 90 rows just take everything on the driver directly and do your stuff ..

Comment: is it possible to have a nested structure in a dataframe? the resulting documents should be 2 level jsons before saving to MongoDB

Comment: Yes, see [Spark structs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.html).